Custom Fonts Not Applied Globally in Flutter; Only Works When Set for Each Widget?
I'm working on a Flutter app and have configured custom fonts in my pubspec.yaml file. While the fonts appear to work correctly when I apply them explicitly to each widget, they do not seem to be applied globally across the app.
Here’s the relevant part of my pubspec.yaml where I define the custom fonts:
pubspec.yaml (Font Configuration):
  fonts:
    - family: Cairo
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Cairo-VariableFont_slnt,wght.ttf
          weight: 700


main.dart
 MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Cairo',
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Otp(),

i tried to make a custom fontbut it dosent work

Also add textTheme to ThemeData with your required fontsize and give fontfamily to every text, e.g. textTheme: TextTheme(bodyText1: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Cairo'),)
and restart your app.
